# In php how to store/send the results of a button click to a reloaded or different page?

Tags: php

this is likely a basic question but I don't know the terminology to properly look it up. Using php/mysql.

1) Four small images below a larger image. When one of the small images is clicked the page reloads with the smaller image in the larger position. How do you send the click info?

2) Same as above but it goes to a new page that loads the smaller image

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit hard to understand you, but assume you want to pass some parameters.
GET parameters are passed within an URL like this: http://blah.com/script.php?param1=value1&param2=value2.

Answer (score 0):

Look into get and post for PHP. You use either to obtain variables in URLs, with these variables you can acheive your button size functionality. I don't think you need SQL for what you're trying to do.